# Hiding div on ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

This hide/show script currently loads the div as visible when the page is downloaded. What do I change in the script so the #box div begins as hidden?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var hidden = false;
$('.arrow').click(function () {
    if (hidden) {
        hidden = false;
        $('#box').slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        hidden = true;
        $('#box').slideUp("slow");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function () { $('#box').hide() //your code});

Comment: Why wouldn't you put it in the CSS?

Comment: yeah you can avoid that glitchy hiding behaviour with a css rule

Comment: Questions like this make me miss the `homework` tag.

Comment: Wow... This question begs for a `i-absolutely-refuse-to-use-my-brain` tag!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/aGCxB/1)***

Use jQuery's [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/). It will set the `#box` as `display:none`. The `slide` functionality will still work when the click even occurs.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#box').hide();//use this
 var hidden = true;
 $('.arrow').click(function () {
  if (hidden) {
    hidden = false;
    $('#box').slideDown("slow");
  } else {
    hidden = true;
    $('#box').slideUp("slow");
  }
 });
});
```

Or, as [`@undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848164/undefined) points out, you can use [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) like this:

***[`jsfiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/aGCxB/2/)***

```
$('#box').hide();//use this
$('.arrow').click(function () {
 $('#box').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: You need to change the initial value of `hidden` to reflect the change.

Comment: _... or use `slideToggle`!_

Comment: @undefined - I wasn't trying to change their code that much, but I can add a slideToggle demo too! :P

Comment: Travis & @Barmar - your help is very much appreciated ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#box').hide();
    var hidden = true;
    $('.arrow').click(function () {
        if (hidden) {
            hidden = false;
            $('#box').slideDown("slow");
        } else {
            hidden = true;
            $('#box').slideUp("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You're still setting `hidden` to false.